# Why the CV in smaller test set perform better than a bigger test set?

Tags: r, machine-learning, multiple-regression, cross-validation, random-forest

I have a question about cross-validation.

I use random forests (RF) for regression forecast. I use a daily data from day 1 to day 365. In this case, I have the dataset from the year 2011 to the year 2014. I divide the dataset into 2 types: one-year and four-year dataset. Then, I build the RF algorithm with these dataset and validate by 10-fold CV. The results show that the CV-R2 of one-year dataset is higher than four-year dataset. Also, the CV-RMSE of one-year dataset is smaller than the four-year dataset.

It would be great if you could suggest me about the reason why the CV in one-year dataset outperform the CV in four-year dataset. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not say anything about your particular data and the statistical model you use, it is hard to guess. Here is a general cosidreation:

When the data in the different years are independent, traing the model with four years should yield better results than training with only one year. If there is a trend, however, and the data in one year depends on the previous year, only trianing the model with the previous year will yield better results.

If there is a trend over the course of a year, it might be worthwhile not to group the data by year, but to use the timestamp as the predictor variable for a local regression like LOESS.